# Is somebody trying to hack me?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall, tcp, acl

Does this mean, that someone is trying to get login over SSH/Telnet to my ASA?
If not, can someone explain me this log?

[image]

When there only is a `Built outbound UDP connection 6947 for outside:8.8.8.8/53 (8.8.8.8/53) to inside:10.0.0.168/48411 (PublicIP/48411)` it means that I have opened a Website in Browser and it sends me an Response - Am I right?

Comment: Short version: YES. But not *you* specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this mean that someone is trying to get login over SSH/Telnet to
>   my ASA?

Well, yes.   But you can expect to see that hundreds or thousands of times a day.   Welcome to the Internet.  If you don't allow SSH or telnet from the outside interface, this is just noise.

> it means that I have opened a Website in Browser and it sends me an
>   Response - Am I right?

It means you have made a DNS query to Google.  If it were a website, you would see a connection to TCP port 80.

Comment: Its my first time seeing the log. I think I arrived at the Internet. So these are some scripts which try all IPs in the world if they can login over SSH and Telnet, just to hack someone? So I shouldn't get stressed about this?
Okay thanks! :-)

Comment: Additionally, it's not uncommon to see ping sweeps (if you have multiple public IPs behind your firewall) and port scans throughout the day.  Be careful that you don't overwhelm your logs with this stuff.

Comment: I saved the log. In 12 Hours "only" 40 attemps. This is crazy :o

Answer (score 3):

watch the logs for a day.  there will thousands of attempts to access your public servers on a bunch of well known ports.

But i would not be worried.  it happens all day and night.  people actually trying to 'hack' your network or just some school kid that got a hold of metasploit

Comment: This will continue 24x7x365. The attempts are automated, especially for known residential networks. This is because home users are typically naive about security.

Comment: So some people are espacially looking for home networks, just to do something bad? I knew that there is a lot of things going on in the internet, but i didn't knew that it's so much. But thanks for the information. I will study all the log entrys.